# How to Send Message to Destination List in Message Broker..?

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

**Greetings to all smart people around here !!**

I am newbie to WebSphere Message Broker,I have Question like this..

**Question**

create a sample flow to receive the XML message from the queue and send it to the destination list..

I will send Output to Particular Queue Name through MQ-OUTPUT but How to send it to the destination list..?

Comment: @animusion In going thought to clean up the [ibm] tag for burnination I ran across this question.  It appears that you closed it after it already had a valid answer.  dave who answered it know what the OP was asking and provided an answer.  I agree the question does not provide the most detail, but does it deserve to be a closed status?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the MQ Output Node into "Destination List" mode using the "Destination Mode" property in the Advanced Tab on the node.

You can then set the local environment values `OutputLocalEnvironment.Destination.MQ.DestinationData[X].queueName = <queueName>`

For example take a look at the function given in Infocenter topic http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac16862_.htm

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE addToMQDestinationList(IN LocalEnvironment REFERENCE, IN newQueue char) BEGIN
  /*******************************************************************************
  * A procedure that adds a queue name to the MQ destination list in the local environment.
  * This list is used by an MQOutput node that has its mode set to Destination list.
  *
  * IN LocalEnvironment: the LocalEnvironment to be modified. 
  * IN queue: the queue to be added to the list
  *
  *******************************************************************************/
DECLARE I INTEGER CARDINALITY(LocalEnvironment.Destination.MQ.DestinationData[]);
        IF I = 0 THEN
            SET OutputLocalEnvironment.Destination.MQ.DestinationData[1].queueName = newQueue;
        ELSE
            SET OutputLocalEnvironment.Destination.MQ.DestinationData[I+1].queueName = newQueue;
        END IF;
    END;
```

Comment: Hi Dave,when calling addToMQDestinationList procedure,how to pass parameters for LocalEnvironment and newQueue...?

Comment: Something like "CALL addToMQDestinationList(OutputLocalEnvironment, 'myQueueName');" should get you there.